# Enable Rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

rewrite not working, this is my `nginx -V` and installed via 'apt-get' how to enable ['rewrite'](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) module ?

```
root@server:~# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.9
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed' --with-ipv6
```

This is my location confs

```
    # Location
    location / {
            # include /etc/nginx/cors.conf;
            try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
```

Comment: rewrite is always included. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton `drupal` gives me 404 on the inner pages, so i tried to see the copied packages. thats why this question .. any clue ?

Comment: Just checked - rewrite module is included & working in Ubuntu. Check if there are errors in your config files. You can start with [official nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/) or [drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/110224) examples.

Comment: @Anubioz, okay its working `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` saved me thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes `rewrite is always included` thanks

Comment: @NikhilM By the way, nginx treats unknown configuration directives as an error and won't have started if there was no rewrite module included...